# NestJS 8 own AuthGuard & Passport: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined

Tags: passport.js, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I have own implementation of AuthGuard:

```
import { authenticate } from 'passport';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext){
    ...
    authenticate(...); 
  }
}
```

When I call `authenticate` method I get: `Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined at  Authenticator.authenticate (.../node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:162:26`

It looks like Passport hasn't been started.

AuthModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

and AppModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule
    ]    
 })
export class AppModule {}
```

This code was working in Nest 7.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Try importing passport as `import * as passport from 'passport'` and doing `passport.authenticate()`. It seems weird, but it may be related to Typescript 4.4

Comment: ou thank you, It works. I have tried this but eslint warning me "authenticate' not found in imported namespace 'passport'" so in the end I didn't even run the code